# Application Early Flush JSON Format

Tags: json, facebook

The Facebook developer app has a field called "Early Flush" that tells Facebook to load your static resources right away for Canvas Applications. For example, your style.css and/or javascript.js files. It requires JSON format, but I can't figure out for the life of me what format its looking for. I've tried all sorts of variations of [] and {}. The old discussion forums indicates it needs to be in this format, but this doesn't make sense nor does it work. http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=91799

```
[{
    "name":"All", 
    "pattern":".*", 
    "resources":
        ["http://www.myapp.com/resource.css", 
         "http://www.myapp.com/flash.swf"]
}]
```

Can anyone tell me how to format this so that Facebook loads my style.css and javascript.js files quickly?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Canvas Prefetching section of this document:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

I think what you need is FB.Canvas.Prefetcher.addStaticResource

Comment: Thanks, a search for "Early Flush" wasn't showing anything on developers.facebook.com. This looks to be an alternate way to programmatically specify the static resources. However, I'm concerned that since best practice is to load the FB JS API asynchronously, wouldn't this call to FB.Canvas.Prefecher wait to be executed until the page already loaded fully?

Comment: Further. I've checked the Graph API Explorer at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer and it shows that Facebook isn't "smart enough" to determine what to pre-fetch for whatever reason.